# PHP: checking files from two directories (or recursively over subdirectories)

Tags: php

I would appreciate if I can ask a question about php.

In my website, I will use a file "timestamp.php" under public_html to display the time between updating files in directory "public_html."

```
$dir = dir($directory); // get directory handler
while(($file = $dir->read())  !== false) { // read the directory in loop
    if($file == '..') continue; // this is the parent folder
    if($file == '.') continue; // this is the current folder  // this is the php file
```

Let me call this website as a 'formal site'.

Now I want to create a 'development site' but sharing the same time counter: that is, updating the 'development_site' will also update a counter displayed at the formal site.

I set up the 'development site' at public_html/development_site. (I am not sure whether this is the best place to put a 'development_site,' but as a starter)

But at this moment updating files in public_html does update the counter, but updating files in public_html/development_site will not update the counter.

Thus I need to set timestamp.php to look for files in public_html/development_site. I like to know how to modify timestamp.php to check files in public_html/development_site.

I have tried

```
$directory= "/nfs/.../public_html"; 
$devdirectory="/nfs/.../public_html/development_site"; 
$dir = dir($directory); // get directory handler
$dir2=dir($devdirectory);//
while((($file = $dir2->read())  !== false)|| (($file = $dir->read())  !== false))
 { // read the directory in loop
    if($file == '..') continue; // this is the parent folder
    if($file == '.') continue; // this is the current folder  // this is the php file
```

But it does not update counter when a file is updated in development directory. I will appreciate comments.

Here is the entire code.

```
<?php
$stats_array = array();
$counter = 1;

$directory = "/nfs/.../public_html";

$devdirectory = "/nfs/.../public_html/dev";

if(is_file('/nfs/.../filestat.txt')) {
    $file_array = file('/nfs/.../filestat.txt');
    foreach($file_array as $line) {
        // tab delimited timestamp, filename, counter
        $line = trim($line);
        if(!empty($line)) {
            $line_array = explode("\t",$line);
            $stats_array[md5($line_array[1])] = $line_array;
        }
    }
}

$files = array(); // create empty array


$dir = dir($directory); // get directory handler

$dir2 = dir($devdirectory); // get directory handler

while(($file = $dir->read())  !== false) { // read the directory in loop
    if($file == '..') continue; // this is the parent folder
    if($file == '.') continue; // this is the current folder  // this is the php file
    if(strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.jpeg') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.xml') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.gif') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.png') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.png') !== false) continue;
    if(strpos($file, '.html') == false) continue; // this is the html file
    if($file == '.htaccess') continue; // this is the security file
    if($file == 'filestat.txt') continue; // this is the stats file
    $file = $directory . '/' . $file;
    if(is_dir($file)) continue; // this is the folder
    if(!file_exists($file)) continue;
    $fileinfo = new SplFileInfo($file); // get file info object
    // put the file info into an array with UNIXTIME key.
    $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = array('name'=>$file,'mtime'=>date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),'unixtime'=>$fileinfo->getMTime());
    $key = md5($file);
    if(array_key_exists($key, $stats_array)) {
        if($stats_array[$key][0] != date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime())) {
            $stats_array[$key][2]++;
            $stats_array[$key][0] = date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime());
        }
    } else {
        $stats_array[$key] = array(
            date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),
            $file,
            1
        );
    }
    $datetime = new \DateTime();
    $datetime->setTimestamp($fileinfo->getMTime());
    $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%H:%I:%S');
    if($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') != '0')
    {
        $days = ($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') == '1') ? ' day ' : ' days ';
        $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') . $days . $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'];
    }
} 


$dir->close(); // close the handler

ksort($files); // sort array by keys in ascending order
$newest_file = array_pop($files); //extract latest file from array

foreach($stats_array as $stat) {
    $counter += $stat[2];
}

printf(
    "Counter %s. (%s) Time Since the Last upload: <span class='update_time' mtime='%s'>%s</span>.",
    $counter,
    $newest_file['mtime'],
    $newest_file['unixtime'],
    $newest_file['age']// this is formatted date and time string
);



$put = '';
foreach($stats_array as $line) {
    $put .= implode("\t",$line)."\n";
}
file_put_contents('/nfs/.../filestat.txt',$put);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete solution that works for me, tested in debugging environment with `php v7.3.19-1~deb10u1`:

```
<?php

/*-----
 CONFIG
------*/
$filestat_path = "/nfs/.../filestat.txt";
$directory = "/nfs/.../public_html";
$devdirectory = "/nfs/.../public_html/dev";
/*-----*/


$stats_array = array();
$counter = 1;


if(is_file($filestat_path)) {
    $file_array = file($filestat_path);
    foreach($file_array as $line) {
        // tab delimited timestamp, filename, counter
        $line = trim($line);
        if(!empty($line)) {
            $line_array = explode("\t",$line);
            $stats_array[md5($line_array[1])] = $line_array;
        }
    }
}

$files = array(); // create empty array

$dir1 = dir($directory); // get directory handler
$dir2 = dir($devdirectory); // get directory handler

$switch = true; //we change this to false as we want to switch to $dir2

do {
    //if    true         this    if not   this
    $file = $switch ? $dir1->read() : $dir2->read(); //dynamically assigning $dir1 or $dir2 to $file according to value of $switch
    $crdir = $switch ? $directory : $devdirectory;
    if ($file !== false) {
        //
        //Your loop handling
        //
        
        if($file == '..') continue; // this is the parent folder
        if($file == '.') continue; // this is the current folder  // this is the php file
        if(strpos($file, '.jpg') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.jpeg') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.xml') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.gif') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.png') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.png') !== false) continue;
        if(strpos($file, '.html') == false) continue; // this is the html file
        if($file == '.htaccess') continue; // this is the security file
        if($file == 'filestat.txt') continue; // this is the stats file
        $file = $crdir . '/' . $file;
        if(is_dir($file)) continue; // this is the folder
        if(!file_exists($file)) continue;
        $fileinfo = new SplFileInfo($file); // get file info object
        // put the file info into an array with UNIXTIME key.
        $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()] = array('name'=>$file,'mtime'=>date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),'unixtime'=>$fileinfo->getMTime());
        $key = md5($file);
        
        if(array_key_exists($key, $stats_array)) {
            if($stats_array[$key][0] != date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime())) {
                $stats_array[$key][2]++;
                $stats_array[$key][0] = date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime());
            }
        } else {
            $stats_array[$key] = array(
                date('Y:m:d:H:i:s', $fileinfo->getMTime()),
                $file,
                1
            );
        }
        $datetime = new \DateTime();
        $datetime->setTimestamp($fileinfo->getMTime());
        $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%H:%I:%S');
        if($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') != '0')
        {
            $days = ($datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') == '1') ? ' day ' : ' days ';
            $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'] = $datetime->diff(new \DateTime())->format('%a') . $days . $files[$fileinfo->getMTime()]['age'];
        }
        
        //
        //END Your loop handling
        //
    }
    elseif ($switch === true) { //switch to $dir2 if not already
        $switch = false;
    }
    else { //if already switched to $dir2, exit loop
        break;
    }
} while (true);

$dir1->close(); // close the handler
$dir2->close();

ksort($files); // sort array by keys in ascending order
$newest_file = array_pop($files); //extract latest file from array

foreach($stats_array as $stat) {
    $counter += $stat[2];
}

printf(
    "Counter %s. (%s) Time Since the Last upload: <span class='update_time' mtime='%s'>%s</span>.",
    $counter,
    $newest_file['mtime'],
    $newest_file['unixtime'],
    $newest_file['age']// this is formatted date and time string
);



$put = '';
foreach($stats_array as $line) {
    $put .= implode("\t",$line)."\n";
}
file_put_contents($filestat_path,$put);
?>
```

Notice the `CONFIG` section I added at the top, here you can set and change the paths, they are used everywhere in the script, so you only have to change one value.

## Explanation

I basically made a loop that is going through the main directory first and afterwards through the development directory (switching of the `$file` variable's value is done with the `$switch` variable, which affets what value is being asigned), all specified by the path variables in the highlighted config area.
Then follows the basically unchanged handling code provided by you, which already does the thing, since all values are stored into one variable an the sorting at the end simultaneosly does the "show only the most recent change of both directorys" thing.
**Important** to notice is one change though, that has to be made to this code:
The line

```
$file = $directory . '/' . $file;
```

has to be changed to

```
$file = $crdir . '/' . $file;
```

with adding the following line above the `if ($file !== false)`, too:

```
$crdir = $switch ? $directory : $devdirectory;
```

to work with our "value-swapping" of the both directories.

Comment: Your point does seem to make sense. This code is supposed to calculate the time since the last upload. Thus one needs to take a min of time since last upload in the main directory and time since last upload in the dev directory. Here is the entire code. Will you take a look how to modify the code?

Comment: @user12586 So everything of this already works and you only want to make the same iteration for your dev version?

Comment: Yes this works for one directory. One now wants to extend so that one can display the time since the upload in either of these two directories.

Comment: @user12586 I updated my answer, I hope I understood your issue correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I think the following can be done. First, calculate the time since last update from the main directory using the sample code. Second, calculate the time since last update from the dev directory using the sample code. Then output the time since last update that is smaller of the two. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: @user12586 Ah, you want to only print the most recent one of the two directorys?

Comment: @user12586 I just updated my answer with the new, full script. I tested it in my debugging environment and it worked fine. Please tell me if this works for you and is the solution you wanted!

Comment: @user12586 I'm pleased to hear that! Would you mind upvoting/accepting my answer? :)